# Sitemap / Breadcrumb not showing up with Url routing on default page

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing, sitemap

I've got my web forms site (4.0) setup with UrlRouting.
My bread crumb appears when I go to

- http://Localhost/Home
- http://Localhost/List

My main issue is with  http://Localhost/

Since it's defaulting to http://Localhost/default.aspx in IIS

I'm trying to avoid the route of adding another element to the sitemap xml  like

```
<siteMapNode url="~/Home" title="Home"  description="Home" aspx="default.aspx">
```

What would be the best approach to use?

I've tried to add this to my routing table & using an xmlSiteMapProvider to see if I could so something with it (which didn't work).

```
routes.MapPageRoute("IISDefault", "", "~/Default.aspx");
```

Here's some of info.

```
Routes
routes.MapPageRoute("Default", "Home", "~/Default.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("ListAll", "List", "~/ListAll.aspx");

Sitemap
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
    <siteMapNode url="~/Home" title="Home"  description="Home">
        <siteMapNode url="~/List" title="List All"  description="List All"  />
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

XmlSiteMapProvider

```
   /// <summary>
    /// This is where the original sitemap node is overloaded.  We get the proper translation from the database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">This is the sender of the event</param>
    /// <param name="e">This is the event arguments</param>
    /// <returns>Returns a modified SiteMapNode</returns>
    /// <remarks></remarks>
    public SiteMapNode SmartSiteMapProvider_SiteMapResolve(object sender, SiteMapResolveEventArgs e)
    {

        SiteMapNode returnValue = null;

        if ((SiteMap.CurrentNode == null))
        {
            // If we don't find a sitemap node, then we might be working with UrlRouting
            returnValue = ProcessRoute(e);
        }


        return returnValue;

    }

    private SiteMapNode ProcessRoute(SiteMapResolveEventArgs e)
    {

        SiteMapNode returnValue = null;

        System.Web.Routing.RequestContext rc = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext;

        if ((rc != null))
        {
            System.Web.Routing.RouteBase route = rc.RouteData.Route;

            if ((route != null))
            {
              // Play with the node (Never getting here)
            }
        }

        return returnValue;

    }
```

Edit: I'm going to see if I can manipulate the routeCollection to get a match somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of :

```
Routes
routes.MapPageRoute("Default", "Home", "~/Default.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("ListAll", "List", "~/ListAll.aspx");

Sitemap
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
    <siteMapNode url="~/Home" title="Home"  description="Home">
        <siteMapNode url="~/List" title="List All"  description="List All"  />
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

try this:

```
Routes
routes.MapPageRoute("Default", "Home", "~/");
routes.MapPageRoute("ListAll", "List", "~/ListAll.aspx");

Sitemap
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
    <siteMapNode url="~/" title="Home"  description="Home">
        <siteMapNode url="~/List" title="List All"  description="List All"  />
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

Otherwise "~/" and "~/Home" are the same thing.

or you could leave the above as is and in the default.aspx page do something like this ...

```
if(Page.RouteData.Values[0] == "default.aspx")
    Response.Redirect("~/Home")
```

That would effectively redirect any default request to your default request.

Your problem is that the server sees ~/" and "~/Home" as being 2 different urls and you basically want them to be the same, so you have to make a decision and decide which one to redirect to the other.

personally if this was my solution I would'nt have a route for "~/Home" and my base node in my sitemap would look something like this:

```
<siteMapNode url="~/" title="Home"  description="Home">
```

It's clean and obvious that "http://yourdomain/" is the homepage and "http://yourdomain/Home" could be anything (about your home, my home, home sweet home, things i like in my home) whereas "http://adomain/" is the homepage across the globe for everyone.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Wardy.  I'll have to get back into the swing of things for this code.  It's been awhile.  I tried to put your url="~/" title="home" in my sitemap but to no avail.  The breadcrumb doesn't come up when I go to Http://yourdomain.

Comment: What are you expecting to see in the breadcrumb ??? ... for a homepage technically there isn't a breadcrumb because the bread crumb shows the path back to the root from your current location thus the homepage is kind of an exception ... I tend to hard code a link to ~/ if i feel its relevant ... thing is ... if you're on the homepage why would you show a link to the homepage ?

Comment: Good point, I always assumed that if you were on the homepage, it would just say Home but without a link.  From my quick google search, people just remove it from the homepage.  Thanks for the tip

Comment: Yeh some people do like to do that, i'm a big fan of "don't link to this page" but showing "Home > page > nested page" if your on nested page and making nested page not link to anything is a cool way to go. Homepages are kind of an exception to breadcrumbs when you're on them because there is no logical path.